# Get lagged data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the lagged data from a dataset. The dataset is monthly and looks like this:

```
           Final Profits
JCCreateDate    
2016-04-30  31163371.59
2016-05-31  27512300.34
...
2019-02-28  16800693.82
2019-03-31  5384227.13
```

Now out of the above dataset, I've selected a window of data (last 12 months of data) from which I want to subtract 3,6,9 and 12 months.

I've created the window dataset like this:

```
df_all = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('window_dataset.csv')
data_start, data_end = pd.to_datetime(df.first_valid_index()), pd.to_datetime(df.last_valid_index())
dr = pd.date_range(data_start, data_end, freq='M')
```

Now for the daterange `dr` I wanted to subtract the months, lets suppose I subtract 3 months from `dr` and try to retrieve the data from `df_all`

```
df_all.loc[dr - pd.DateOffset(months=3)]
```

which gives me following output

```
            Final Profits
2018-01-30  NaN
2018-02-28  9240766.46
2018-03-30  NaN
2018-04-30  13250515.05
2018-05-31  12539224.15
2018-06-30  17778326.04
2018-07-31  19345671.02
2018-08-30  NaN
2018-09-30  14815607.14
2018-10-31  28979099.74
2018-11-28  NaN
2018-12-31  12395273.24
```

As one can see I've got some NaN because the months like Jan, Mar has got 31 days and the subtraction is searching for the wrong day of the month. How to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you are looking for but I suspect use shift.

```
# set up dataframe
index = pd.date_range(start='2016-04-30', end='2019-03-31', freq='M' )
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5000000, 50000000, 36), index=index, columns=['Final Profits'])

# create three columns shifting and subtracing from 'Final_Profits'
df['3mos'] = df['Final Profits'] - df['Final Profits'].shift(3)
df['6mos'] = df['Final Profits'] - df['Final Profits'].shift(6)
df['9mos'] = df['Final Profits'] - df['Final Profits'].shift(9)

print(df.head(12))

         Final Profits        3mos        6mos        9mos
2016-04-30       45197972         NaN         NaN         NaN
2016-05-31        5029292         NaN         NaN         NaN
2016-06-30       20310120         NaN         NaN         NaN
2016-07-31       10514197 -34683775.0         NaN         NaN
2016-08-31       31219405  26190113.0         NaN         NaN
2016-09-30       21504727   1194607.0         NaN         NaN
2016-10-31       19234437   8720240.0 -25963535.0         NaN
2016-11-30       18881711 -12337694.0  13852419.0         NaN
2016-12-31       27237712   5732985.0   6927592.0         NaN
2017-01-31       21692788   2458351.0  11178591.0 -23505184.0
2017-02-28        7869701 -11012010.0 -23349704.0   2840409.0
2017-03-31       20943248  -6294464.0   -561479.0    633128.0
```